# How to solve svn error E155010?

Tags: svn

My working copy is in an inconsistent status:

```
$ svn status
svn: E155037: Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted
$ svn cleanup
svn: E155010: The node '<myprojectpath>/libs/armeabi/gdbserver' was not found.
```

I'm stucked on it. There is a solution to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: may be related. http://grokbase.com/t/subversion/users/121a68zz1j/possible-bug-in-1-7-svn-cleanup-cant-recover-after-a-failed-update-with-1-6-it-was-possible

Comment: Link is dead, you can use https://web.archive.org/web/20130607065955/http://grokbase.com/t/subversion/users/121a68zz1j/possible-bug-in-1-7-svn-cleanup-cant-recover-after-a-failed-update-with-1-6-it-was-possible

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found that is quite simple to solve (in my case).
Open a console and go to the folder presenting the problem (in you case `<myprojectpath>/libs/armeabi/gdbserver`).

Run `svn up`. It will show you a line presenting the same error `svn: E155010:...`.

```
lore@loreLaptop ~/workspace/Ng
$ svn up
Updating '.':
svn: E155010: The node '/home/lore/workspace/Ng/.classpath' was not found.
```

Run `svn cleanup`.

```
lore@loreLaptop ~/workspace/Ng
$ svn cleanup
```

Run `svn up` again: a menu will be showed allowing you to edit/resolve/accept/... a particular configuration:

```
lore@loreLaptop ~/workspace/Ng
$ svn up
Updating '.':
Conflict for property 'svn:ignore' discovered on '/home/lore/workspace/Ng'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
        (s) show all options: s

  (e)  edit             - change merged file in an editor
  (df) diff-full        - show all changes made to merged file
  (r)  resolved         - accept merged version of file

  (dc) display-conflict - show all conflicts (ignoring merged version)
  (mc) mine-conflict    - accept my version for all conflicts (same)
  (tc) theirs-conflict  - accept their version for all conflicts (same)

  (mf) mine-full        - accept my version of entire file (even non-conflicts)
  (tf) theirs-full      - accept their version of entire file (same)

  (p)  postpone         - mark the conflict to be resolved later
  (l)  launch           - launch external tool to resolve conflict
  (s)  show all         - show this list

Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
        (s) show all options: e
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit, (r) resolved,
        (s) show all options: r
 U   .
Updated to revision 193.
Summary of conflicts:
  Skipped paths: 2
```

Run `svn up` to be sure that the conflict is resolved:

```
lore@loreLaptop ~/workspace/Ng
$ svn up
Updating '.':
At revision 193.
Summary of conflicts:
  Skipped paths: 2
```

That's all. Hope could be useful for someone.

Comment: I was seeing this error in Eclipse/Subversive. This solution worked for me. All I needed to run was `svn up` from the command line in the directory of the offending file. Voted up.

Comment: I didn't accept your answer because it never worked for me, happy to see that many people found it useful.

Comment: I case this error happens because a file was deleted after changes were added you need to use `svn delete <filename>`

Answer (score 8):

svn 1.7: it has happened to me after trying to add to SVN a directory tree not owned by me. It failed and got stuck with the same OP's error.

It resulted that there was some entry in table `work_queue` of the *sqlite* SVN file that SVN was unable to process, either because of permissions or because I removed the file afterward.

I solved it with:

```
> sqlite3 .svn/wc.db
SQLite version 3.6.20
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> delete from work_queue;
sqlite> .quit

> svn cleanup
```

Then recursively reverted and all was fine again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after I have started using xCode5. Whenever I do a fresh checkout, I am getting files properly but whenever I try to do a diff or try to check-in certain files, it used to give me E155010 error saying that the node was not found.

I tried svn cleanup and all and it didn't work (svn up didn't give any error) . In fact the issue was happening for all my colleagues also. Did a round of research on this but couldn't find out a fix. So finally as a work around we started using SvnX client and with that the things are working fine.

[SVNX Home Page](http://code.google.com/p/svnx/)

Answer (score 1):

Check for problems with uppercase or lowercase not corresponding to Svn path.
When I eliminate the problem of uppercase or lowercase not corresponding, I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Under Eclipse + Cygwin, this did it for me:

1. Go to container folder, `svn cleanup`.
2. Go to Eclipse, select container folder, `Team > Update`. If it is ok with you, you can also *Replace from repository*.

Answer (score 0):

It also happened to me, and the cause is somewhat related to what Sigismondo reported:

I had copied a bunch of text files in my local directory. I wanted to call `svn setprops` on *.txt to make them `text/plain` and had forgotten about the extra files (which I don't want to commit).

The solution was to temporary move these "extra" files elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had to adapt the answer given by @baronKarza slightly.

As my particular SVN project is littered with "externals", i have to append the "--include-externals" to the svn cleanup command.

```
    svn cleanup --include-externals
```